# Can we access the Trading Panel tab in pine script using TradingView?

Tags: pine-script

Since we can't import data into TradingView from external sources yet, is there any way to access the contents of the Trading Panel tab?  This is the tab adjacent to the Strategy Tester tab, and integrates with a broker.

There are fields such as NAV and Account Balance which I'd like to access from Pinescript in my study or strategy script.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen there is limited access to these calculations.

Kodify has the best resources on available meta information for a strategy so far grouped here:

[Strategy Info](https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-info/)

Which includes how-to's to retrieve *some* information like:

- [Open and Closed Trade Counts](https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-info/closed-open-trades/#summary)
- [Winning, Losing, and Even Trades](https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-info/wins-losses-evens/)
- [Sizing TradingView orders based on a percentage of the strategy's equity](https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/order-size-equity-percentage/)

But that's all I'm aware of so far.